# DocuSign signing: send e-mail + sms

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope with the sending of email and sms, I contacted docusing support, they said they activated the sms in the demo version, but when sending the envelope I don't receive any error from the SDK, the email arrives but the sms doesn't. Here's a part of the code in java and Json

```
public java.util.List<com.docusign.esign.model.Signer> getInSmsSigners() throws Exception {
    java.util.List<com.docusign.esign.model.Signer> signers = new java.util.LinkedList<com.docusign.esign.model.Signer>();
    String READ_SIGNERS_QUERY =
            "SELECT eap.*, e.in_open_cc" +
                    "  FROM envelope_assinatura_proposta eap " +
                    " INNER JOIN envelope e ON e.cd_envelope = eap.cd_envelope " +
                    " WHERE eap.cd_pessoa_governanca IS NULL " +
                    "   AND eap.cd_envelope = ?; ";

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(READ_SIGNERS_QUERY);
    ps.setDouble(1, Double.parseDouble(numProposta));
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    SignersPhones signersPhones = new SignersPhones();

    while (rs.next()) {
        com.docusign.esign.model.Signer sms = new com.docusign.esign.model.Signer();
        com.docusign.esign.model.RecipientPhoneNumber phone = new com.docusign.esign.model.RecipientPhoneNumber();
        if (rs.getString("nr_telefone") != null) {

            com.docusign.esign.model.Signer signer = new com.docusign.esign.model.Signer();
            signer.setName(rs.getString("nm_pessoa"));
            signer.setRecipientId(rs.getString("seq_envelope"));
            signer.setRoutingOrder(rs.getString("ordem_ass"));
            signer.setDeliveryMethod("SMS");

            RecipientAdditionalNotification smsDelivery = new RecipientAdditionalNotification();
            smsDelivery.secondaryDeliveryMethod("SMS");

            RecipientPhoneNumber telefonesms = new RecipientPhoneNumber();
            telefonesms.setCountryCode("+".concat(rs.getString("nr_ddi")));
            telefonesms.setNumber(rs.getString("nr_ddd").concat(rs.getString("nr_telefone")));

            smsDelivery.phoneNumber(telefonesms);
            signer.setAdditionalNotifications(Arrays.asList(smsDelivery));
            signer.setPhoneNumber(telefonesms);

            signers.add(signer);
            System.out.println("Telefone é " + telefonesms);
        }
    }
    return signers;
}

List<com.docusign.esign.model.Signer> phoneNumbers = this.getInSmsSigners();
            if (phoneNumbers.size() > 0) {
                signerTabs.setNumberTabs((List) phoneNumbers);
            }
            List<Checkbox> checkboxes = this.getCheckbox(numProposta, rs.getString("seq_envelope"));
            if (checkboxes.size() > 0) {
                signerTabs.setCheckboxTabs(checkboxes);
            }
            signer.setTabs(signerTabs);
            signers.add(signer);



 signers: [class Signer {
        accessCode: null
        accessCodeMetadata: null
        addAccessCodeToEmail: null
        additionalNotifications: null
        agentCanEditEmail: null
        agentCanEditName: null
        allowSystemOverrideForLockedRecipient: null
        autoNavigation: null
        autoRespondedReason: null
        bulkRecipientsUri: null
        canSignOffline: null
        clientUserId: null
        completedCount: null
        creationReason: null
        customFields: [Titular]
        declinedDateTime: null
        declinedReason: null
        defaultRecipient: null
        delegatedBy: null
        delegatedTo: null
        deliveredDateTime: null
        deliveryMethod: null
        deliveryMethodMetadata: null
        designatorId: null
        designatorIdGuid: null
        documentVisibility: null
        email: isantos@uniprimebr.com.br
        emailMetadata: null
        emailNotification: null
        emailRecipientPostSigningURL: null
        embeddedRecipientStartURL: null
        errorDetails: null
        excludedDocuments: null
        faxNumber: null
        faxNumberMetadata: null
        firstName: null
        firstNameMetadata: null
        fullName: null
        fullNameMetadata: null
        idCheckConfigurationName: null
        idCheckConfigurationNameMetadata: null
        idCheckInformationInput: null
        identityVerification: null
        inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration: null
        isBulkRecipient: null
        isBulkRecipientMetadata: null
        lastName: null
        lastNameMetadata: null
        lockedRecipientPhoneAuthEditable: null
        lockedRecipientSmsEditable: null
        name: IGOR ROMAO SANTOS
        nameMetadata: null
        notaryId: null
        notarySignerEmailSent: null
        note: null
        noteMetadata: null
        offlineAttributes: null
        phoneAuthentication: null
        phoneNumber: null
        proofFile: null
        recipientAttachments: null
        recipientAuthenticationStatus: null
        recipientFeatureMetadata: null
        recipientId: 1
        recipientIdGuid: null
        recipientSignatureProviders: null
        recipientSuppliesTabs: null
        recipientType: null
        recipientTypeMetadata: null
        requireIdLookup: null
        requireIdLookupMetadata: null
        requireSignerCertificate: null
        requireSignOnPaper: null
        requireUploadSignature: null
        roleName: null
        routingOrder: 101
        routingOrderMetadata: null
        sentDateTime: null
        signatureInfo: null
        signedDateTime: null
        signInEachLocation: null
        signInEachLocationMetadata: null
        signingGroupId: null
        signingGroupIdMetadata: null
        signingGroupName: null
        signingGroupUsers: null
        smsAuthentication: null
        socialAuthentications: null
        status: null
        statusCode: null
        suppressEmails: null
        tabs: class Tabs {
            approveTabs: null
            checkboxTabs: null
            commentThreadTabs: null
            commissionCountyTabs: null
            commissionExpirationTabs: null
            commissionNumberTabs: null
            commissionStateTabs: null
            companyTabs: null
            currencyTabs: null
            dateSignedTabs: null
            dateTabs: null
            declineTabs: null
            drawTabs: null
            emailAddressTabs: null
            emailTabs: null
            envelopeIdTabs: null
            firstNameTabs: null
            formulaTabs: null
            fullNameTabs: null
            initialHereTabs: null
            lastNameTabs: null
            listTabs: [class List {
                anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters: null
                anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharactersMetadata: null
                anchorCaseSensitive: null
                anchorCaseSensitiveMetadata: null
                anchorHorizontalAlignment: null
                anchorHorizontalAlignmentMetadata: null
                anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: null
                anchorIgnoreIfNotPresentMetadata: null
                anchorMatchWholeWord: null
                anchorMatchWholeWordMetadata: null
                anchorString: /cbox_7_1/
                anchorStringMetadata: null
                anchorTabProcessorVersion: null
                anchorTabProcessorVersionMetadata: null
                anchorUnits: null
                anchorUnitsMetadata: null
                anchorXOffset: null
                anchorXOffsetMetadata: null
                anchorYOffset: null
                anchorYOffsetMetadata: null
                bold: null
                boldMetadata: null
                conditionalParentLabel: null
                conditionalParentLabelMetadata: null
                conditionalParentValue: null
                conditionalParentValueMetadata: null
                customTabId: null
                customTabIdMetadata: null
                documentId: null
                documentIdMetadata: null
                errorDetails: null
                font: null
                fontColor: null
                fontColorMetadata: null
                fontMetadata: null
                fontSize: null
                fontSizeMetadata: null
                formOrder: null
                formOrderMetadata: null
                formPageLabel: null
                formPageLabelMetadata: null
                formPageNumber: null
                formPageNumberMetadata: null
                height: null
                heightMetadata: null
                italic: null
                italicMetadata: null
                listItems: [class ListItem {
                    selected: null
                    selectedMetadata: null
                    text: Sim
                    textMetadata: null
                    value: S
                    valueMetadata: null
                }, class ListItem {
                    selected: null
                    selectedMetadata: null
                    text: Não
                    textMetadata: null
                    value: N
                    valueMetadata: null
                }]
                listSelectedValue: null
                listSelectedValueMetadata: null
                localePolicy: null
                locked: null
                lockedMetadata: null
                mergeField: null
                mergeFieldXml: null
                pageNumber: null
                pageNumberMetadata: null
                recipientId: 1
                recipientIdGuid: null
                recipientIdGuidMetadata: null
                recipientIdMetadata: null
                requireAll: null
                requireAllMetadata: null
                required: null
                requiredMetadata: null
                requireInitialOnSharedChange: null
                requireInitialOnSharedChangeMetadata: null
                senderRequired: null
                senderRequiredMetadata: null
                shared: null
                sharedMetadata: null
                smartContractInformation: null
                source: null
                status: null
                statusMetadata: null
                tabGroupLabels: null
                tabGroupLabelsMetadata: null
                tabId: null
                tabIdMetadata: null
                tabLabel: 7
                tabLabelMetadata: null
                tabOrder: null
                tabOrderMetadata: null
                tabType: null
                tabTypeMetadata: null
                templateLocked: null
                templateLockedMetadata: null
                templateRequired: null
                templateRequiredMetadata: null
                tooltip: null
                toolTipMetadata: null
                underline: null
                underlineMetadata: null
                value: null
                valueMetadata: null
                width: null
                widthMetadata: null
                xPosition: null
                xPositionMetadata: null
                yPosition: null
                yPositionMetadata: null
            }, class List {
                anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters: null
                anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharactersMetadata: null
                anchorCaseSensitive: null
                anchorCaseSensitiveMetadata: null
                anchorHorizontalAlignment: null
                anchorHorizontalAlignmentMetadata: null
                anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: null
                anchorIgnoreIfNotPresentMetadata: null
                anchorMatchWholeWord: null
                anchorMatchWholeWordMetadata: null
                anchorString: /cbox_8_1/
                anchorStringMetadata: null
                anchorTabProcessorVersion: null
                anchorTabProcessorVersionMetadata: null
                anchorUnits: null
                anchorUnitsMetadata: null
                anchorXOffset: null
                anchorXOffsetMetadata: null
                anchorYOffset: null
                anchorYOffsetMetadata: null
                bold: null
                boldMetadata: null
                conditionalParentLabel: null
                conditionalParentLabelMetadata: null
                conditionalParentValue: null
                conditionalParentValueMetadata: null
                customTabId: null
                customTabIdMetadata: null
                documentId: null
                documentIdMetadata: null
                errorDetails: null
                font: null
                fontColor: null
                fontColorMetadata: null
                fontMetadata: null
                fontSize: null
                fontSizeMetadata: null
                formOrder: null
                formOrderMetadata: null
                formPageLabel: null
                formPageLabelMetadata: null
                formPageNumber: null
                formPageNumberMetadata: null
                height: null
                heightMetadata: null
                italic: null
                italicMetadata: null
                listItems: [class ListItem {
                    selected: null
                    selectedMetadata: null
                    text: Sim
                    textMetadata: null
                    value: S
                    valueMetadata: null
                }, class ListItem {
                    selected: null
                    selectedMetadata: null
                    text: Não
                    textMetadata: null
                    value: N
                    valueMetadata: null
                }]
                listSelectedValue: null
                listSelectedValueMetadata: null
                localePolicy: null
                locked: null
                lockedMetadata: null
                mergeField: null
                mergeFieldXml: null
                pageNumber: null
                pageNumberMetadata: null
                recipientId: 1
                recipientIdGuid: null
                recipientIdGuidMetadata: null
                recipientIdMetadata: null
                requireAll: null
                requireAllMetadata: null
                required: null
                requiredMetadata: null
                requireInitialOnSharedChange: null
                requireInitialOnSharedChangeMetadata: null
                senderRequired: null
                senderRequiredMetadata: null
                shared: null
                sharedMetadata: null
                smartContractInformation: null
                source: null
                status: null
                statusMetadata: null
                tabGroupLabels: null
                tabGroupLabelsMetadata: null
                tabId: null
                tabIdMetadata: null
                tabLabel: 8
                tabLabelMetadata: null
                tabOrder: null
                tabOrderMetadata: null
                tabType: null
                tabTypeMetadata: null
                templateLocked: null
                templateLockedMetadata: null
                templateRequired: null
                templateRequiredMetadata: null
                tooltip: null
                toolTipMetadata: null
                underline: null
                underlineMetadata: null
                value: null
                valueMetadata: null
                width: null
                widthMetadata: null
                xPosition: null
                xPositionMetadata: null
                yPosition: null
                yPositionMetadata: null
            }]
            notarizeTabs: null
            notarySealTabs: null
            noteTabs: null
            numberTabs: [class Signer {
                accessCode: null
                accessCodeMetadata: null
                addAccessCodeToEmail: null
                additionalNotifications: [class RecipientAdditionalNotification {
                    phoneNumber: class RecipientPhoneNumber {
                        countryCode: +55
                        countryCodeMetadata: null
                        number: 43996519226
                        numberMetadata: null
                    }
                    secondaryDeliveryMethod: SMS
                    secondaryDeliveryMethodMetadata: null
                    secondaryDeliveryStatus: null
                }]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `phoneNumber` object is not inside `additionalNotification` object and not inside the **numberTabs** object. You just put phone Number under the signer object directly.

Also, try **55** instead of **+55** for the `countryCode`

Full example code here: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/eSignature/services/SMSDeliveryService.java

Snippet of relevant Java code:

```
    RecipientPhoneNumber phoneNumber = new RecipientPhoneNumber();
    phoneNumber.setCountryCode(countryCode);
    phoneNumber.setNumber(signersPhoneNumber);

    Signer signer = new Signer();
    signer.setName(signerName);
    signer.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    signer.setRecipientId("1");
    signer.setRoutingOrder("1");
    signer.setTabs(signerTabs);
```

I recommend you download the Java quickstart, it will have working code and you can figure out how it's working - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Comment: do you have an example of how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [live example with 6 software languages](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=SMS%20and%20email%20delivery)

It uses the API request builder application.